# Update mysql field using CONCAT and SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

**EDIT**

After removing my silly mistake of `INTO` (I was working with INSERTS and just keep going) the error below is showing. Still not working:

> Affected rows: 0
>
> [Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'tbl'
>   for update in FROM clause

---

I'm trying to create an update where I select all the previous data in the column, add a complementary string and save it as new data. The code is below (with the error)

Using only the select, the result:

```
set @id = 3;

SELECT tbl_alias.string_id 
FROM tbl as tbl_alias
WHERE id = @id

-- the output `3,10,8,9,4,1,7,11,5,2,6,12`
```

I also tried with this query (the output is what I want)

```
SELECT CONCAT((
    SELECT tbl_alias.string_id 
    FROM tbl as tbl_alias
    WHERE id = @id
),',13,14,15,16') AS X

-- the output `3,10,8,9,4,1,7,11,5,2,6,12,13,14,15,16`
```

But after replacing the select below. It brings the same error.

**The query**

```
set @id = 3;

UPDATE INTO tbl 
SET string_id = 
    CONCAT((
        SELECT tbl_alias.string_id 
        FROM tbl as tbl_alias
        WHERE id = @id
    ),',13,14,15,16') WHERE id = @id;
```

**The error**

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ' INTO tbl  SET string_id =      CONCAT((        SELECT
>   tbl_alias.string_id ' at line 1

---

It's probably the `CONCAT` together with `SELECT`. But I didn't find the solution...

Comment: You are using INTO on an UPDATE (used on an INSERT but not for an UPDATE).

Comment: I was working with inserts, I just keep going. The error persists after removing `INTO`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Do you need the sub query?

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET string_id = CONCAT(string_id, ',13,14,15,16')
WHERE id = @id;
```

Note that in MySQL you cannot modify using an UPDATE the table that is used in the sub query (although there are fiddles around it):-

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subqueries.html

> *In MySQL, you cannot modify a table and select from the same table in a subquery. This applies to statements such as DELETE, INSERT,
>   REPLACE, UPDATE, and (because subqueries can be used in the SET
>   clause) LOAD DATA INFILE.*

Comment: I need the data inside the column. `string_id` == ??

Comment: You original update appears to be adding ',13,14,15,16' onto the end of the field string_id. That is what this query does.

Comment: The second query in my question answer your question

Comment: I want to get the data in the column, add extra info and save it again. "-- the output `3,10,8,9,4,1,7,11,5,2,6,12,13,14,15,16`"

Comment: If you are just doing the update then I think the sub query is not required, as you can just concat ',13,14,15,16' onto the end of string_id. If string_id had a value of `3,10,8,9,4,1,7,11,5,2,6,12` then this update would result in it now having a value of `3,10,8,9,4,1,7,11,5,2,6,12,13,14,15,16`

Comment: Worked. I was stupid on this one. Thanks for showing me the obvious, and sorry for the trouble. :X

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `UPDATE` without `INTO`:

```
set @id = 3;

UPDATE tbl 
SET string_id = 
    CONCAT((
        SELECT tbl_alias.string_id 
        FROM tbl as tbl_alias
        WHERE id = @id
    ),',13,14,15,16') WHERE id = @id;
```

**Update:**

Try this:

```
set @id = 3;

UPDATE tbl 
SET string_id = 
    CONCAT(SELECT string_id FROM (
        SELECT tbl_alias.string_id 
        FROM tbl as tbl_alias
        WHERE id = @id
    ) t1 ,',13,14,15,16') WHERE id = @id;
```

Comment: `Affected rows: 0` **and** `[Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'tbl' for update in FROM clause`. btw, was a silly mistake of mine, thanks for pointing that out. Still not working =/

Comment: `[Err] 1583 - Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'CONCAT'`

Answer (score 0):

This case helps sometimes to update **ALL** column data for *TESTING* purpose:

```
UPDATE customer_profile 
  SET businessId = CONCAT(businessId, ' new customer ', (id + 1))
```