# MySQL add data to row after existing data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add new data right after the current data. This works well,

```
mysql_query("UPDATE uyeler SET shoots=shoots + 1 WHERE nick='admin'")
```

However, its only for numbers. I tried that with normal text value

```
$places = "london";
mysql_query("UPDATE uyeler SET shootplaces= shootplaces + '".$places."' WHERE nick='admin'")
```

But all it does is that it makes the shootplaces to 0. What is the correct way to add new value to a row without deleting the current value in it ?

Comment: menace you need addition of two text? or just Concatenate of two string?

Comment: I need to add new data to shootplaces row, after the current row data (without deleting it).

Comment: What contain `shootplaces ` ?

Comment: Is `shootplaces` an integer?

Comment: @Sadikhasan "New york, dubai"

Comment: Use `CONCAT()` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use Mysql [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.

```
$places = "london";
mysql_query("UPDATE uyeler SET shootplaces= CONCAT(shootplaces , '".$places."') WHERE nick='admin'")
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your shootplaces has INT as datatype ?
Anyway, you can use `concat()` function to add new data into new cell.

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET your_column = CONCAT(your_column, 'your new value') WHERE id=..
```

[See this link for further help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378231/update-mysql-field-using-concat-and-select?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: are you adding multiple values to a single column? That violates first normal form.
or are you merely adding to a string. to me it looks like you are going to store multiple locations in one column.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
$places = "london";
     mysql_query("UPDATE uyeler SET shootplaces= concate(shootplaces , '$places') WHERE nick='admin'")
```